# Nodejs Mocha Test using Zombie getting Wrong Document Error

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, zombie.js

I fairly new to node and mocha and brand new to Zombie.  I am trying to write some functional tests for my application.  It is built using node/express.  And when you try to log into a page (the dashboard in my example) it will redirect you to the login.  Upon logging in, it will send you back to the requested page.  On the dashboard, there is a button to click that will take you to an offer summary page.  (These pages do use requirejs to load the necessary javascript)

I am trying to test that scenario using Mocha and I am able to test the redirect to login and then the loading the original page.  However, when I pressButton for the offerSummary I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Wrong document
      at Object.core.Node.insertBefore (..zombie/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/level1/core.js:501:13)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../zombie/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/level2/events.js:314:20)
      at Object.proto.(anonymous function) [as insertBefore] (../node_modules/zombie/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/utils.js:21:26)
      at Object.core.Node.appendChild (../zombie/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/level1/core.js:621:17)
      at Function.l.load (/javascripts/requirejs/require.2.1.2.min.js:33:148)
      at Object.j.load (/javascripts/requirejs/require.2.1.2.min.js:28:351)
```

Here is my mocha test

```
describe.only('dashboard', function() {
    var browser;
    beforeEach(function(done){
        var routeToVisit = "/dashboard";
        browser = new Browser();

        browser.on("error", function(err) {
            done(err);
        });

        browser.visit(startingUrl + routeToVisit, function(){

                browser.location.pathname.should.equal("/login.html");

                browser.fill("#username", "abc");
                browser.fill("#password", "abc");
                browser.pressButton("#login", function (res){
                    browser.location.pathname.should.equal(routeToVisit);
                    done();
                });
            });
    });

    it('offers dashboards should redirect correctly', function(done){

        should.exist(browser.query("#dbOffers"));
        should.exist(browser.query("#dbOffersValue"));
        should.exist(browser.query("#dbOffersText"));
        browser.pressButton("#dbOffers", function(res){
            browser.location.pathname.should.equal("/offerSummary");
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.